# Adding HTML to the search page

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin that will update the search results page by adding some sponsored listings above and below the results.

I've tried to use `is_search()`  but that will only return true if a search returns results, additionally  `is_search()`  only tells me when a search occurs.

Now that i know how to catch search, either thorough  `is+search or looking for $_GET['s']` I need to be able to add some HTML to the actual search results page.

Can someone help me determine what action or hook to use please.

Can i do something with the_loop? or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one my function what i use to play and manipulate with search. Maybe can help.

```
/*** Suggested Keywords for search ***/
function get_suggested_keywords(){
    /* Suggested keywords + tags */
    if(isset($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['s']))
    {
        $search=preg_replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]","",urldecode($_GET['s']));
        if(!empty($search))
        {
            $words=array_map("trim",explode(" ",$search));
            if(isset($words[1]) && !empty($words[1]))
            {
                $tags=array();
                foreach($words as $tag)
                {
                    $tags[]= '<a href="' . get_site_url() . '/?s=' . $tag . '" title="' . $tag . '" rel="search">' .$tag. '</a>';
                }
                echo '<h3 class="general-title">
                        <span>'.__('Suggested keywords', 'creativform').'</span>
                    </h3>'."\r\n";
                echo '<div class="tagcloud">'.join($tags, " &nbsp; ").'</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a lot of variations of this but you can use this keywords to call query and play with that data.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to reorganize your content and add extra content into your post you need first to loop all posts from database, save in array, add extra contet in array and list all data in HTML in new loop. Here is example:

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

    $keys = array_keys($list); 
    shuffle($keys); 
    $random = array(); 
    foreach ($keys as $key) $random[$key] = $list[$key];
    return $random; 
} 
$query=array();
if(have_posts()){
    #### Get posts and save for manipulation ####
    while (have_posts()){ 
        the_post();
        // get the ID
        $ID = get_the_ID();
        // get thumbnail
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' );
        if(isset($thumb[0]) && !empty($thumb[0])) 
              $thumbnail=$thumb[0]; 
        else 
              $thumbnail=false;
        // save in object array
        $query[]=(object)array(
            'thumbnail'             =>  $thumbnail,
            'post_permalink'        =>  post_permalink($ID),
            'the_title_attribute'   =>  the_title_attribute(array('echo' => 0)),
            'the_title'             =>  get_the_title($ID),
            'the_content'           =>  get_the_content($ID),
            'the_date'              =>  get_the_date($ID),
        );
    }

    #### Add new content inside posts ####
    $query[]=(object)array(
            'thumbnail'             =>  "SOMETHING 1",
            'post_permalink'        =>  "SOMETHING 1",
            'the_title_attribute'   =>  "SOMETHING 1",
            'the_title'             =>  "SOMETHING 1",
            'the_content'           =>  "SOMETHING 1",
            'the_date'              =>  "SOMETHING 1",
        );
    $query[]=(object)array(
            'thumbnail'             =>  "SOMETHING 2",
            'post_permalink'        =>  "SOMETHING 2",
            'the_title_attribute'   =>  "SOMETHING 2",
            'the_title'             =>  "SOMETHING 2",
            'the_content'           =>  "SOMETHING 2",
            'the_date'              =>  "SOMETHING 2",
        );

    #### Randomize content (OPTIONAL - delete if you don't need or just comment) ####
    $query=shuffle_assoc($query);

    #### Loop and display in your HTML ####
    foreach($query as $fetch){
        echo $fetch->thumbnail.'<br>';
        echo $fetch->post_permalink.'<br>';
        echo $fetch->the_title_attribute.'<br>';
        echo $fetch->the_title.'<br>';
        echo $fetch->the_content.'<br>';
        echo $fetch->the_date.'<br>';

        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

In area where you add new content, you can add manualy or to use some loop with check of keywords to grab other content in similar way and store in `$query`. You can use this code in posts lists, page lists, search, etc. with small modification in WP_query();

Comment: hi Ivijan how do you use this? Do you call a function within the theme edit? Or does your plugin inject this into the search results (which is what i'm looking to do)

Comment: I just use `get_suggested_keywords()` to display keywords from search query. If you need some array of keywords, you need to remove echo's and HTML from this and add `return $tags;`. After that you can in PHP call array for other proccess. Do you need some explanation?

Comment: ok, so you use a shortcode to then render this? Or is this used within a widget? I can get the query strings, but i'm actually trying to change the HTML of the search results and prepend sponsored listings above the results. But i cant figure out the action to use. add_action('the_content', callback) will be applied to each post returned and not the actual results. so i'm a bit stuck.

Comment: I will update now my answer